# Unity, Application.OpenUrl how to open local pdf file with cyrillic symbols in path?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, openurl

I'm trying to open local pdf file using Application.OpenUrl method. The trouble is in the path to file. It works fine when it is only latin symbols(e.g. path = "file:///" + "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/file.pdf") 
but path = "file:///" + "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Отчеты/file.pdf" doesn't work.

Does Application.OpenUrl method supports cyrillic symbols in path?

Thanks to you

Comment: Have you tried googling? Maybe this thred will help https://answers.unity.com/questions/874892/problems-with-russian-characters-within-strings-c.html

Comment: Also you have to add specific errors that you get